# Suppressing JavaFX CSS errors in Eclipse?

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx-2

Following this JavaFX 2.0 [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/css.htm) I created a css file in eclipse that includes the line

```
  -fx-fill: FIREBRICK;
```

Now that color is unknown to Eclipse and therefore marked as an error. How can I surpress this warning (as the color does exist in JavaFX) or better: How to make Eclipse aware of the fact that this color does exist in JavaFX?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write it in lower case the tooling doesn't show an error. I've filed ticket http://efxclipse.org/trac/ticket/142 to support upper and lower case

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out and reporting :-) Seems like you even fixed it? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try efxclipse addon. Author states there is CSS support: http://efxclipse.org/#about-tooling

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I have that already installed. Also didn't find a special CSS type for FXML in the presets.

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work :( You may want to try to ask a question on efxclipse plugin forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/efxclipse